# Galois groups and braid groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, galois-theory, braid-groups

Braid group can be viewed as a symmetry group with a "one more dimension to pass through". Is there any "Galois theory", where the braid groups plays analoguos role as a symmetry groups in a native Galois theory? Can this be related to the purposes of low-dimensional topology?

Comment: This question strikes me as a little vague. Can you be more precise about what you're looking for and what you might want such a notion to do? 

Comment: Construct an object like algebraic equation and a system of "roots", which symmetry can be described by a braid group.
More preciesly - I'am thinking about a new machinery that can be used to describe knots naturally, some "equations" related to knots and some "groups of permutations of roots" which preserves isotopy.


Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking exactly, but there are well-known analogies between the knot group (the fundamental group of a knot complement) and certain Galois groups. See for instance http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3399. I'm not aware of Galois-theoretic analogues of the braid group though.

Comment: Have a look at this paper:
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1204.4242

Comment: The braid groups are fundamental groups (of configuration spaces of points in the plane) so we have a standard Galois correspondence.